# MVVM and passing parameters with IoC

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

Using Prism.Unity, I'm having trouble understanding how am I supposed to construct certain objects without passing parameters because that way I would break the benefits of IoC as I would have to specify a concrete class.

What I'm trying to build for now is quite simple: a view showing a list of items, and those items have some commands related to themselves.

Creating the host view which contains the following:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Maquinas}"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Zona" Binding="{Binding Area}" Width="140"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre" Binding="{Binding Descripcion}" Width="350"/>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Acciones">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Width="30" Height="30" Command="{Binding VerMaquinaCommand}" Margin="0" ToolTip="Ver máquina"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

And getting the components is quite simple:

```
public class MaquinasListaViewModel : BindableBase, IMaquinasListaViewModel, INavigationAware
{
    [Dependency]
    public IMaquinasListaModel Model { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<IMaquinasListaMaquinaViewModel> Maquinas { get; } = new ObservableCollection<IMaquinasListaMaquinaViewModel>();
    public MaquinasListaViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<RefreshEvent>().Subscribe(Iniciar, ThreadOption.UIThread, false, obj => obj.ViewModel == this);
        Iniciar();
    }
    public void Iniciar(RefreshEventArgs args = null)
    {
        foreach (Maquina m in Model.ObtenerTodas())
        {
           // How do I create here MaquinasListaMaquinaViewModel passing them the info on which Maquina are based
           // This was my attempt but fails on DI because I create the instance myself so I force the type. 
           // I can't resolve a IMaquinasListaMaquinaViewModel associated with a particular Maquina, 
           // unless I first resolve it and then inject the value on a property? But then I could have and invalid VM.
           // Maquinas.Add(new MaquinasListaMaquinaViewModel(m, Model, _eventAggregator, _navigationService));
        }
    }
```

But how I resolve a `IMaquinasListaMaquinaViewModel` letting it know which `Maquina` is it about?

What is wrong with my architecture? Because I feel like something smells bad...

Comment: Where does the Maquina object come from in the first place? If this is something that you select in some list or navigate to at runtime it doesn't make much sense to resolve the view model from a container. Then you could create a specific instance of the view model class - for example using a factory - and inject it with the model. You could still resolve the other dependencies of the view model class, like the IEventAggregator, using the container.

Comment: @mm8 the model creates all the Maquina objects and serves them to the viewmodel of the list view. So you say that if I create the object in a factory with Maquina as parameter 1 and eventAggregator as parameter 2, how do I pass the first one from the factory but get the other one injected?

Comment: I still don't understand how the Model property of the view model is currently set and from where?

Comment: @bb8 The Model property is set by Unity DI as it has the [Dependency] over it.